# Modal ViewController with custom transition = wrong animation

Tags: uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, catransition

In my application it's possible to open a video from pretty much everywhere. The video player a UIViewController subclass which contains an MPMoviePlayerController and is presented on the rootViewController of my application.

I use the following code to present a ViewController in my app, with the custom transition to

```
// When the glitch occurs, the rootViewController still has a presentedViewController
if (self.rootViewController.presentedViewController)
     [self.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];

CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;

UIWindow* window = self.appDelegate.window;
[window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.rootViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:^{}];
```

99% of the time this works fine, with the desired result, but sometimes, really randomly I get a very weird glitch. The video player ViewController is visible and the rootViewController of my app slides in from the right on top of my video player.

So basically, the transition is applied to the rootViewController rather than the video ViewController. At this point it becomes impossible to open a video in my app because the rootViewController does the right to left transition on top of a video player ViewController.

How can I prevent this glitch from occurring? I tried to dismiss any active presentedViewController from the rootViewController before presenting a new one but that doesn't solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.